# python dict: dynamically read a layered dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this dict ("one", "two" and "four" always exist but might be empty):

```
info = {
  "one":1,
  "two":{
    "three":3,
    "almost_three":3.5
  },
  "four": {
    "five":{
      "six":6 
    }
  }
}
```

my condition code is this:

```
if info['one']:
  sum += info['one']
if info['two'].get('three'):
  sum += info['two']['three']
if info['two'].get('almost_three'):
  sum += info['two']['almost_three']
if info['four'].get('five'):
  sum += info['four']['five']
```

you can see how this is getting repetitive breaking the DRY principle...

my hope was doing something like this (in pseudocode):

```
NUMS = [['one'],['two, three'],['two, almost_three'],['four, five','six']]
for key_args in NUMS:
  if info.get(key_args):
    sum += info.get(key_args)
```

I am using python version 3.8 but not critical

Given I have many keys and many values in the dict
HOW do I remove all the repetitive code (DRY principle)
but still maintain a list of keys to read that can go deeper than 1 level?

side note: the main issue is that I have infinite key/values and I only want to read only the ones in my NUMS list

Comment: Are you trying to get the sum of all values?

Comment: So did you try writing some _non_-pseudo code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @arsho, yes but some of the values I don't need so I want to specify exactlly which ones I do need

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion to sum the values of a nested dictionary:

```
def sum_values(d):
    total = 0
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            total += sum_values(v)
        else:
            total += v
    return total


info = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": {
        "three": 3,
        "almost_three": 3.5
    },
    "four": {
        "five": {
            "six": 6
        }
    }
}

print(sum_values(info))
```

Output:

```
13.5
```

Comment: Why add `k` also? You could simply do `for v in d.values()`.

Comment: Though, I must say it's a great approach!

Comment: like it, but the main issue is that I have infinite key/values and I only want to go through the one in my NUMS list

Comment: @eladsilver the `NUMS` list contain a nested list. Does the hierarchy of the data matter? If it does not, you can change the keys in the `else` block like `elif k in NUMS: total += v`